# Tableview not reloading custom accessory type

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I'm trying to implement a "Done" method through a custom slide left on an item in a table view.
[image]
But when I click the "done" button it doesn't update my custom cell accessory type. **(Found in the "editActionsForRowAtIndexPath" function (or search for "//mark as completed")")** I've literally tried everything I could think of for many hours and I'm just stuck. Please note I'm very new to this, so if you could help me out in understandable words that would be great.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cellIdentifier = "Cell"
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as CustomTableViewCell

    // Configure the cell...
    let bucketLists = (searchController.active) ? searchResults[indexPath.row] : bucketList[indexPath.row]

    cell.nameLabel.text = bucketLists.name
    cell.thumbnailImageView.image = UIImage(data: bucketLists.image)
    cell.locationLabel.text = bucketLists.location
    cell.typeLabel.text = bucketLists.type

    if (bucketLists.isVisited == true) {
        cell.favorIconImageView.hidden = false // Don't hide custom cell accessory if true

    } else if (bucketLists.isVisited == false) {
        cell.favorIconImageView.hidden = true
    }


    // Circular image
    cell.thumbnailImageView.layer.cornerRadius = cell.thumbnailImageView.frame.size.width / 2
    cell.thumbnailImageView.clipsToBounds = true

    return cell
}



override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [AnyObject]? {


    // Delete Button
    var deleteAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: UITableViewRowActionStyle.Default, title: "Delete",handler: {
        (action:UITableViewRowAction!, indexPath:NSIndexPath!) -> Void in

        // Delete the row from the data source
        if let managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate).managedObjectContext {

            let bucketListToDelete = self.fetchResultController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as BucketList
            managedObjectContext.deleteObject(bucketListToDelete)

            var e: NSError?
            if managedObjectContext.save(&e) != true {
                println("delete error: \(e!.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }

    })

    // Mark as Completed Button
    var completedAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: UITableViewRowActionStyle.Default, title: "Done",handler: {
        (action:UITableViewRowAction!, indexPath:NSIndexPath!) -> Void in

        println("Completed item \(indexPath.row)")


        let cellIdentifier = "Cell"
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as CustomTableViewCell

        // Configure the cell...
        let bucketLists = (self.searchController.active) ? self.searchResults[indexPath.row] : self.bucketList[indexPath.row]

        cell.favorIconImageView.hidden = false // Item completed so hide the cell accessory image



    })

    deleteAction.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 244.0/255.0, green: 67.0/255.0, blue: 54.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0) // Red
    completedAction.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 3.0/255.0, green: 169.0/255.0, blue: 244.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0) // Blue

    return [deleteAction, completedAction]
}
```

If you need any more info please comment below

Comment: This is way too much code. When you post a question, you should try to keep the code to the part that's relevant to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is this line in the block for the definition of the var, completedAction

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as CustomTableViewCell
```

This instantiates a new cell that never appears in your table view. You want to get a reference to the cell you already have at that indexPath,

let cell = self.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as CustomTableViewCell